# Use Fork() to create three child processes with only 2 grandchild processes

Tags: c, fork

Using fork() to create child process, I am trying to make a tree that looks like this:

```
    p
  / | \
 p  p  p
   / \
  p   p
```

I have the parent create the three children processes, but I can't get the two outside children to stop forking and the second child to only fork twice.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
 {

pid_t lchildpid, rchildpid,mchildpid, parentpid;
int n = 0;
lchildpid = 0;
rchildpid = 0;
mchildpid = 0;


 printf("\nLvl\tProc\tParent\tChild 1\tChild 2\tChild 3\n");
printf("No.\tID\tID\tID\tID\tID\n");

 while(n < 3){


if((lchildpid = fork()) == 0 || (mchildpid = fork()) == 0 || (rchildpid = fork()) == 0) {

        parentpid = getppid();
        n++;
        continue;

    }

    //check for forking errors
    if(lchildpid == -1 || rchildpid == -1 || mchildpid == -1) 
    {
        perror("\n The fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //If current fork has two children, print complete generation to console and exit while loop
    if(lchildpid && rchildpid && mchildpid ){
        printf("%d\t%ld\t%ld\t%ld\t%ld\t%ld\n",n, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)lchildpid, (long)mchildpid,(long)rchildpid);
        break;


      }

 }
       exit(0);
 }
```

Here is my output:

```
   Lvl     Proc    Parent  Child 1 Child 2 Child 3                                                                                                                                   
   No.     ID      ID      ID      ID      ID                                                                                                                                        
    0       22      7       23      24      25                                                                                                                                        
    1       23      1       26      28      32                                                                                                                                        
    1       25      1       29      31      33                                                                                                                                        
    1       24      1       27      30      34
```

I want this output:

```
    Lvl     Proc    Parent  Child 1 Child 2 Child 3                                                                                                                                   
    No.     ID      ID      ID      ID      ID                                                                                                                                        
     0       40      7       41      42      43                                                                                                                                        
     1       41      40       0       0      0                                                                                                                                
     1       42      40      44      45      0                                                                                                                                        
     1       43      40       0       0      0
```

Comment: You *do* know that `||` is short-circuiting?

Comment: Is it required to perform all the forking via a single expression?

Comment: For your reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: No it is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You're dealing with the fact that `fork()` returns *twice* (on success): once in the parent process, and once in the child process.  These cases can be distinguished by the return value.  Since `fork()` *does* return in each child, it doesn't make much sense to assign the values to `lchildpid`, `mchildpid`, and `rchildpid`, because every process will have its own copies of these variables.  If the forking worked as you wanted, then some of those copies would be initialized and others not.

It *is* possible write a single expression that produces the forking pattern you presented, by making use of the short-circuiting behavior of the `&&` and `||` operators and of the fact that the return value of `fork()` evaluates to true in the parent (even when `fork()` fails) and to false in the child.  If you need to do this then think about it a bit and fiddle -- you'll work it out.  Hint: use parentheses as necessary, and if needed you can include an integer constant among your `&&` and `||` operands to direct the result of those operations.

It's a kinda interesting problem to write a single expression that does all the forking.  If you don't *have* to do that, however, then it might be easier to just use `if` or `switch` statements to branch to appropriate behavior for the result of each `fork()`.  That would be more characteristic of how `fork()` is usually used in real programs.

I hope that helps, but if you were looking for someone to do your homework for you, then I'm afraid I'm going to have to disappoint you.

Comment: Sorry, I was not looking for anyone to do my my Hw. I was given a lab about fork()s with no explanation about how they work. I was only told to google it, so i have been piecing together info as i go.